# Why LiveData can receive the last available data automatically?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I am reading LiveData source code, and for this method:

```
public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<?super T> observer) { .. }
```

And this is part of its doc:

> When data changes while the owner is not active, it will not receive
> any updates. If it becomes active again, it will receive the last
> available data automatically.

I was trying to figure out why LiveData can achieve this lifecycle-awareness. I read source code of `setValue` but still couldn't get it. Can anybody help me with the on the general idea?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are not using live data and you are showing list of data with pagination concept . You as user have scroll down to view more and more data and application is calling apis to get data as you scroll . Now you have rotated your device so as developer we know that your activity will be recreated and user will be at initial stage again as all things were destroyed .. Well you can achieve this using `onSaveInstance` but you will have to code and manage yourself ..

So user will have to scroll again to view all data but imagine if you have some mechanism where you get your last updated data whenever activity lifecycle changes so you can easily set data again and allow user to use your app like nothing happened .. and here livedata concept come into picture with lifecycle awareness

Hope this answer will clear your doubts

Edit :-
To understand how they are managing lifecycle , you can visit this link

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc

here is source code method of LiveData class where you can see(at last line) how they are adding lifecycler owne to observer

[image]

Comment: great examples! voted up! Thank you! And, yes I know LiveData has the ability to save and restore the Activity/Fragment's state data (and yes! usually it works with ViewModel, which survives from screen rotation, if we put the livedata into the viewModel then it will be kept automatically by leveraging viewModel's mechanism). Umm, can you please help guide me on how LiveData has the ability to pause sending data and continue sending data to the livedata observer according to the LifecycleOwner (the 1st param in livedata.observe func). Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the update. actually by my understanding, this is the 1st step of how the live data works like, after adding the observer, the next thing should be live data setValue or post value to the observers, and if the observers are active they get notified, otherwise, they won't be notified immediately, instead they get notified after they come back to active again, what confuses me right now is how the data gets stored (temporarily) and re-sent to the observer when they come back. May I have your help on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read the source code of `LiveData.java` (in lifecycle-livedata-core:2.2.0@aar) again, it seems clear to me now.

When adding an observer to LiveData via `liveData.observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { .. } )`, the magic happens in the `observe` method.

In the `observe` method, it puts the `lifecycleOwner` and the `Observer` into a new object called `LifecycleBoundObserver` like this:

```
LifecycleBoundObserver wrapper = new LifecycleBoundObserver(owner, observer);
  // ... some other code
owner.getLifecycle().addObserver(wrapper);
```

Important to note and we can also tell it from the last statement: the `LifecycleBoundObserver` is an instance of LifecycleObserver, that means, it can be notified when the given lifecycleOwner gets state updated, the key lies in the `onStateChanged` method of `LifecycleBoundObserver`.

```
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source,
                @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
            if (mOwner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() == DESTROYED) {
                removeObserver(mObserver);
                return;
            }
            activeStateChanged(shouldBeActive());
        }
```

So:

1. If the lifecycleOwner (the Activity or Fragment) gets DESTROYED, it will remove the observer (the callback observer, not the LifecycleObserver), hence the observer won't be notified for new data once it's DESTROYED.
2. If it is not DESTROYED, it requires the lifecycleOwner in Active states (STARTED or RESUMED), this is restricted by the return value from the method `shouldBeAlive()`, and finally the new data gets delivered to observer callback in the method `activeStateChanged`.

```
        void activeStateChanged(boolean newActive) {
            if (newActive == mActive) {
                return;
            }
            // immediately set active state, so we'd never dispatch anything to inactive
            // owner
            mActive = newActive;
            boolean wasInactive = LiveData.this.mActiveCount == 0;
            LiveData.this.mActiveCount += mActive ? 1 : -1;
            if (wasInactive && mActive) {
                onActive();
            }
            if (LiveData.this.mActiveCount == 0 && !mActive) {
                onInactive();
            }
            if (mActive) {
                dispatchingValue(this);
            }
        }
```

3. If the input param `newActive` is true, then finally it will reach the statement of `dispatchingValue(this)` - the last statement, and if it is false (i.e.: inactive states: PAUSED / STOPPED / DESTROYED), it won't call dispatchingValue(this), thus the observer callback won't be triggered.
4. If the Activity / Fragment goes back to foreground from background, it becomes Active again, then the `LifecycleBoundObserver` will be notified and the `onStateChanged` will be called again, and this time, when calling `activeStateChanged(newActive)`, it passes true, therefore, `dispatchingValue(this)` will be called, and the latest data set via `setValue` or `post` will be picked up, that's the reason for explaining why the Activity can get the last emitted / latest value of LiveData.